# Два скроллбара на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со скроллбарами. Имеется многоуровневое меню навигации слева `id="menu"` и лента с записями.

**Проблема заключается в том, что лента и меню имеют скроллбары: при достижении ползунком конца меню навигации, и попытке прокрутить меню ниже, начинает скроллиться лента.**

**Вопрос:** можно ли как-то закреплять ленту, если пользователь пытается прокрутить скроллбар, у которого и так нижнее положение? Почему-то имею проблемы с такой вещью как `onwheel`.

P.S jQuery не знаю от слова совсем.

Comment: стоп, меню на самом низу, куда дальше крутить? или просто надо выключить атопрокрутку у ленты для удобства?

Comment: Покажите код, без него вам не помочь, можно только гадать

Comment: Да и скриншот интерфейса бы не помешал...

Comment: Есть пара ответов на англоязычном ресурсе [ответ 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125560/prevent-parent-scroll-when-in-child-div) [ответ 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element)

Comment: > или просто надо выключить атопрокрутку у ленты для удобства?
**именно это и хочу сделать**

Answer (score 3):

> Почему-то имею проблемы с такой вещью как `onweel`.

Потому что событие называется `wheel`.
И, поскольку событие `scroll` является неотменяемым, придётся работать с `wheel`.

Answer (score 3):

Иногда надо не мудрить и просто поменять разметку.

Если скролл есть у элемента над которым мышь и у одного из его родительских, то скроллится дочерний, а если он уже закончился, то родительский. А в следующем варианте элементы не вложены друг в друга, поэтому скроллятся независимо.

```css
html, body, aside, main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

aside, main {
  overflow: auto;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

aside:before, main:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 150vh;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}

main:before {
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, green);
}
```

```html
<aside></aside>
<main></main>
```

Comment: Первый раз вижу такие вещи, поэтому могу задать глупый вопрос? Что  за вещь такая `:before`, при попытке что-то положить внутрь `<aside></aside>` это что-то появляется только внизу, оставляя мне пустой промежуток от aside:before

Comment: @IsinMin, ну так это как раз и есть это "что-то". Всё что касается `:before` надо удалить и просто положить внутрь контент.

Comment: @IsinMin, если скролл есть у элемента над которым мышь и у одного из его родительских, то скроллится дочерний, а если он уже закончился, то родительский. А в этом варианте элементы не вложены друг в друга, поэтому скроллятся независимо.

Comment: Убрала before и всё почему-то поехало.

Comment: @IsinMin, предполагалось, что левая панель не будет пустой. Если она может быть пустой, добавь для неё `min-height: 1px;`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно на событие прокрутки навигации повесить `event.stopPropagation()`, что должно предотвратить распространение скролла на родительские элементы.